# Inverse Trigonometric Functions and Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, inverse-function

```
 equn = {Cos[L/a] == Cos[ph] Cos[del], Sin[gm] == Sin[a ph/L],Sin[si]
 == Sin[a del/L], Sqrt[1 - Cos[si]^2 - Cos[gm]^2] == a/L} ; NSolve[equn, {ph, si, del, gm}]
```

How to use Reduce NSolve? I could not, please help.

Comment: Since you tried using `NSolve` do you have numeric values for `a` and `L`? With numbers perhaps I can solve it. To make it simpler I replaced `a/L` with a new variable `aL` and simplified the system to `equn={Cos[1/aL]==Cos[ph] Cos[del], Sin[gm]==Sin[aL ph], Sin[aL del]^2-Cos[gm]^2==aL^2}; Reduce[equn,{ph,del,gm}]` but it still times out. Any result from this would need to be carefully checked that it satisfies the original problem.

Comment: $a=1; L=2.2 ;$ that did not appear in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the information on `a` and `L`

I squared both sides of your last equation to avoid negative values inside Sqrt. Then I summed the square of the difference of all your equations.

```
a=1;L=2.2;
equn=(Cos[L/a]-Cos[ph]Cos[del])^2+
  (Sin[gm]-Sin[a ph/L])^2+
  (Sin[si]-Sin[a del/L])^2+
  (1-Cos[si]^2-Cos[gm]^2-a^2/L^2)^2;
NMinimize[equn, {ph, si, del, gm},Method->RandomSearch]
```

very quickly returns

```
{7.95101*^-30,{ph->-5.49111,si->-1.16554,del->-2.56419,gm->-0.645634}}
```

Please test that very carefully before you depend on it.

Comment: Thanks. I also posted a sine signal with your least squares method on SEMath. Please comment on the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete solution, but perhaps it will help

```
equn = {Cos[L/a] == Cos[ph] Cos[del], Sin[gm] == Sin[a ph/L], 
   Sin[si] == Sin[a del/L], Sqrt[1 - Cos[si]^2 - Cos[gm]^2] == a/L};
```

First, I would eliminate as many trig functions as possible, replacing them with simple quadratic relationships (in more variables).  I also reduce the number of constants in the expression.

```
equn2 = (equn /. {Sin[gm] -> sgm, Cos[gm] -> cgm, 
     Sin[si] -> ssi, Cos[si] -> csi, a -> k L})~
  Join~{sgm^2 + cgm^2 == 1, ssi^2 + csi^2 == 1}
(* {Cos[1/k] == Cos[del] Cos[ph], sgm == Sin[k ph], 
 ssi == Sin[del k], Sqrt[1 - cgm^2 - csi^2] == k, cgm^2 + sgm^2 == 1, 
 csi^2 + ssi^2 == 1} *)
```

We can eliminate these new variables (and hopefully solve for them later)

```
Eliminate[equn2, {sgm, cgm, ssi, csi}]
(* -Cos[1/k] + Cos[del] Cos[ph] == 0 && 
 1 + k^2 - Sin[del k]^2 - Sin[k ph]^2 == 0 *)
```

I think that this might be soluble (numerically at least)

Answer (score 1):

- `FindInstance` with `Reals`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a = 1; L = 2.2; 
equn = {Cos[L/a] == Cos[ph]  Cos[del], 
  Sin[gm] == Sin[a  ph/L], Sin[si] == Sin[a  del/L], 
  Sqrt[1 - Cos[si]^2 - Cos[gm]^2] == a/L};
FindInstance[equn, {ph, si, del, gm}, Reals]
```

> `{{ph -> 5.49111, si -> 5.11765, del -> -2.56419, gm -> 2.49596}}`.